# Data migration architecture from on-premises to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, data-migration

For one of our application, the data is stored in organization's on-premise ORACLE database. To generate a nightly report about the sales of past one month they want to create a batch operation but they wish to host it on AWS cloud platform. In order to pull the data from the on-premises database to the cloud, a pipeline has been setup. Now, there is a requirement for a new micro-service, which will require some of the DB tables already being used by the mentioned batch operation. As we are attempting follow separate database per micro-service approach, we will again have to create a data pipeline to replicate the data from on-premise server to the cloud database. However, this solution is not scalable.

Can you please suggest what is the recommended solution for such use cases?

Comment: When your data is migrated to AWS, where/how is it stored and how is it queried? Is it a large volume of data? What is the "data pipeline" you are using?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein the data is stored in AWS RDS Postgres database. We are using a custom data pipeline where data is pushed to Kinesis from the on-premise source and then use a lambda function to store the data in the destination table.